# How to apply textures to a trianglestrip using XNA?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, xna-4.0

I am using XNA to draw 3d primitives.

I have a [TriangleStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.primitivetype.aspx#PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip) that describes a cube (I hope. I used the triangulation shown in Fig2 of [this paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/gvil/papers/av_ts.pdf) ). For those of you that want to check the math:

```
public readonly VertexPositionTexture[] Vertices =
{
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 0,0), new Vector2(1,1)),//A
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 0,0),new Vector2(0,1)),//B
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 1,0),new Vector2(1,0)),//C
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 1,0),new Vector2(0,0)),//D
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 1,1),new Vector2(0,0)),//E
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 0,0),new Vector2(1,1)),//B'
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 0,1),new Vector2(0,1)),//F
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 0,0),new Vector2(1,0)),//A'
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 0,1),new Vector2(1,1)),//H
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 1,0),new Vector2(1,0)),//C'
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 1,1),new Vector2(1,1)),//I
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 1,1),new Vector2(0,0)),//E'
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 0, 0,1),new Vector2(0,1)),//H'
    new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3( 1, 0,0),new Vector2(1,1))//F'
};
```

My problem is, I have no idea how to apply the textures. At first I was trying to apply a different texture to each face but that is proving elusive. What I'm trying to do now is apply a single texture to the entire cube.

First question: is this the best way to proceed? Understanding that I'm trying to create a Cube class that is reusable I will need to apply textures to each face. If that is not possible in a single TriangleStrip then I can stop now.

Second question: How do I apply a single texture to a TriangleStrip properly?

Third question: How do I assign/apply different textures to different faces?

Answer (score 0):

I can't look it up right now, but you have to load the content, too
Moreover use BasicEffect if you are drawing polygons. You should only use SpriteBatch for sprite drawing (ie: using its Draw methods).
Consider to help yourself with google ... ;D just take a look on Microsoft developer Network ... is almost everything explained about the syntax an functions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us

However it would be much easier to draw a model or a mesh via Cinema4D or Blender... and just load the texture on it. -less work to do; more effort / faster and more accurate changes possible.

Hope I helped you good enough ;)

Comment: If you have gotten anything out of MS documentation you are a better man than I am. They give an example of a quad, but no further. And I can't find anything on how to change textures mid-draw.

Comment: dont forget to vote... those documentations aint full explainations... just snippets... you have to look more than on one or start to think: "how can i use it on my programm?". just try things out with their help ;) but you r a bit right... those are more like to refresh your mind :D

Comment: the draw method ... you know where things are being drawn... ;D i htink you should delete the summeries and comments out of the new projects you started xD